# How to use a global variable in vue, it does not update computed variables?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vuetify.js

I'm building a webapp and am now implementing authentication using firebase.
I got the login interface working and now I want to share this data to the rest of the app.

Since I'm not using Vuex I tried using Vue.prototype.$userData= {} to make a global variable so I don't have to worry passing it down.

I create the variable in app.js like this:

```js
  mounted() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        //RETRIEVING SOME EXTRA USER DATA HERE
        firebase
          .firestore()
          .collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
              console.log(doc.data()) //THIS LOG WORKS
              Vue.prototype.$userData = {...user, ...doc.data()};
            } else {
              // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
              console.log('No such document!');
            }
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log('Error getting document:', error);
          });
      }
    });
  }
```

I then tried using it in a component like this:

```js
  computed: {
    username: function () {
      if(this.$userData) {
        return this.$userData.naam;
      } else return "-";
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't seem to update when the $userData finishes. What is going wrong here.
Does the computed not update on a global variable?

P.S. When I make changes to the code so that the build recompiles in the npm run serve, then the username appears. When I then refresh the page it does not work any more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `watch` instead of a computed property.

```
watch:{
  '$userData' = function(newValue){
     ...
     this.name = newValue.name;
     ...
  }
}
```

Get more info at: https://flaviocopes.com/vue-watchers/

PS: assuming, you can access `$userData` throughout the Vue application.